# What are the real benefits of using Cloud Datastore over Cloud Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

As my title states, what are the real benefits of using Cloud Datastore over Cloud Firestore? Or is it better to use Cloud Firestore than using Cloud Datastore in terms of scalability? Thanks!

Comment: Cloud Firestore is the next generation of Cloud Datastore. I think the question that you should be asking is "What are the real benefits of using Cloud Firestore over Cloud Datastore?" :)

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for that resource, it's clear now.